# Can C# generics have a specific base type?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible for a generic interface's type to be based on a specific parent class?

For example:

```
public interface IGenericFace<T : BaseClass>
{
}
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work but if it did, what I'm trying to tell the compiler is that `T` must be a sub-class of `BaseClass`.  Can that be done, are there plans for it, etc.?

I think it would be useful in terms of a specific project, making sure a generic interface/class isn't used with unintended type(s) at compile time.  Or also to sort of self-document: show what kind of type is intended.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
public interface IGenericFace<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
```

Comment: You can find more info on how to constrain the type at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Kyralessa, is it possible to have a generic baseclass

Answer (score 68):

What your are referring to is called "Generic Constraints". There are numerous constraints that can be put on a generic type.

Some basic examples are as follows:

- `where T: struct` - The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except `Nullable` - can be specified. See [Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) for more information.
- `where T : class` - The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.
- `where T : new()` - The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the `new()` constraint must be specified last.
- `where T : <base class name>` - The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.
- `where T : <interface name>` - The type argument must be or implement the specified interface. Multiple interface constraints can be specified. The constraining interface can also be generic.
- `where T : U` - The type argument supplied for `T` must be or derive from the argument supplied for `U`. This is called a naked type constraint.

These can also be linked together like this:

C#

```
public class TestClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged, new() { }
public interface IGenericFace<T> where T : SomeBaseClass
```

VB

```
Public Class TestClass(Of T As {MyBaseClass, INotifyPropertyChanged, New})
Public Interface IGenericInterface(Of T As SomeBaseClass)
```

Answer (score 5):

yes.

```
public interface IGenericFace<T>
    where T : BaseClass
{
}
```

Comment: this should be deleted, I don't see how it is adding anything - Kyralessa already answered this.