# Generics: how to implement: "where T derives from xxx"

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to use a generic class and force one of it's parameters to derive from some base class.
Something like:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }          
public class Manager<T> where T : derivesfrom(BaseClass)
```

The way I'm doing it now is at runtime in the constructor:

```
public class Manager<T> where T : class
{
    public Manager()
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
        {
            throw new Exception("Manager: Should not be here: The generic type should derive from BaseClass");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this at compilation time ?
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230736/can-c-sharp-generics-have-a-specific-base-type

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
public class Manager<T> where T : BaseClass
```

Read all about generic constraints [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).