# Generics class constraint multi level inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Looking for help to put such structure together.

Have base generic class:

```
public class A<T>
    where T: class
{
    public T info { get; set; }    
}
```

Works good for one step inheritance like:

```
class B : A<BInfoClass>{}
```

But need same for higher hierarchy members like, but without making all classes generics:

```
class C : B<CInfoClass>{}
```

Need possibility to have specific "info" type for each B, C, D etc. ("info" classes derive from one base):

Comment: according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) you can add `where T : class, BaseClassName`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can C# generics have a specific base type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230736/can-c-sharp-generics-have-a-specific-base-type)

Comment: edited the question. sorry, maybe haven't understood the answers properly, but still looking for solution

Comment: what is B class you are using in the question ? is it derived from `A` ? you can make it generic like `class B<T> : A<T> where T : class`

Comment: yeah, class B : A<BInfoClass>{}. i'm working in unity and you can't add generic classes as components there properly

Comment: ok this case looks different now, and the duplicate does not fit anymore

Comment: I would just drop the generics in scenario like this. Too much hassle for little gain.

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance. You'd effectively end up with `C` inheriting two `info` properties, and that's just not allowed -- what should the type of `info` be in that case? (I realize you want it to be `CInfoClass`, but there are other reasonable choices.) You need a redesign of your class structure -- exactly what is hard to say with placeholder names. Of course you can always just start using `object` or `dynamic` for the property and force derived classes to cast, but that's clumsy.

Comment: i'm not talking about multiple inheritance, i mean few levels of complexity like A - B - C. i have "executor" classes heirarchy and "info" classes hierarchy. each executor class should have corresponding to it info property

Comment: could you please show your hierarchy levels completely (at least - class definitions with inheritance) ? Generic is about generic code, not about how to get detailed class definitions. Can you use some interface instead ?

Comment: First hierarchy:
`public class A {}`
`public class B : A{}`
`public class C : B{}`.

Second hierarchy:
`public class InfoA:{}`
`public class InfoB: InfoA{}`
`public class InfoC: InfoB{}`.

What i need is to have InfoC in C, InfoB in B and InfoA in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest to add one more level of hierarchy just to make generic class to be `pure` generic.

You can put all common code to the AContainer also.

```
public class AContainer<T> where T : class, InfoA {
  public T info { get; set; } 
} 
public class A : AContainer<InfoA> {}
public class BContainer<T>: AContainer<T> {}
public class B : BContainer<InfoB> {} 
public class CContainer<T>: BContainer<T> {}
public class C : CContainer<InfoC> {}
```

A, B and C classes are empty classes for the `without making all classes generics` condition (to be used in Unity)
AContainer BContainer and CContainer are added to make generic possible here.

However it does not look like a place to use generics

Comment: yeah, big thanks for answers. what do you think is a better way? unfortunately can't put contents of info classes into "execution" classes

Comment: @Sloppy do you really need this inheritance between A, B and C classes ? Can you implement all those classes without inheritance, just class A { AInfo info; } class B { BInfo info; } class C { CInfo info } ?

Comment: i can implement info stuff without inheritance, all in one class (possibly will do so for now), but was looking for better solution

Comment: @Sloppy you have to get some benefit from the inheritance and generics if class hierarchy becomes more complex. Some common algorithms, methods etc.